# 403 error for xampp virtual host after server restart

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp, virtualhost

I am trying to setup a prod. wordpress site on localhost, my first step is to setup a virtual host. following the step to setup virtual host worked but once I shut down xampp and restarted it, I started to get the 403 error

My "httpd-vhosts.conf" file configs are:
[image]

In "httpd.conf" file I have uncommented httpd-vhosts.conf and also set user group accordingly

I also made changes to "httpd-xampp.conf"
changing "require local" > "require all granted"
[image]

After multiple attempts I am still unable to setup virtual host and keep getting the following error
[image]

My access log shows the following log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2023:12:14:47 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 1038
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2023:12:14:47 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 1024
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2023:12:15:07 +0530] "-" 408 -
```

My error log tell me the following:

```
[Wed Feb 08 12:14:47.653295 2023] [core:crit] [pid 88973] (1)Operation not permitted: [client 127.0.0.1:50100] AH00529: /Users/yapsody/Desktop/wordpress/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/Users/yapsody/Desktop/wordpress/' is executable, referer: http://www.yapsody.com/
```

Hoping someone can help me!

Update:
I use a macbook pro intel i5

Comment: Please share more details, like your attempts to resolve the problem. Also, share how this problem is related to PHP or Wordpress itself

Comment: well I am trying to setup wordpress so I thought maybe something in WP is giving the 403 error, also since WP includes PHP I've added that tag too

Comment: The error message from the log sounds like the permissions are not set properly

Comment: in terms of attemps to solve it, I basically searched about it online and every changes that were mentioned for each config file, I've made those changes

Comment: And what did you try to resolve the permission issue?

Comment: 1) go to the DIR > right click and give it read & write acess
2) in the "httpd.conf" user deamon > to [user],  group deamon > [current user]

Answer (score -2):

here are steps for doing what you asked:

1- Install xampp on some hard drive - default is C:

2- Go to C:\xampp\htdocs\

3- Add your project here. (for example, C:\xampp\htdocs\newfolder/index.html)

4- Open a web browser(Chrome, Safari, etc.)

5- Type in address bar:

```
http://localhost/newfolder
```

If you want to run as a site, do this:
1- Go to this file

```
C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
```

At last paragraph, copy last section, paste it twice,
and change it like this:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/"
    ServerName localhost
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/newfolder/index.html"
    ServerName sample.com
 </VirtualHost>
```

then in this file:
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
do this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       sample.com
```

Please don't change commenting, just copy them and then make changes to your copies.

Comment: `some hard drive default is C:`  - that sounds strange. As far as I read the question, XAMPP is already installed, and the OP isn't even using Windows

Comment: yes I use a Mac and also i have followed these steps already and still haven't gotten the result i require